# Enviar apenas os dados dos campos preenchidos por e-mail usando PHP

Tags: php, html, formulário, envio-de-email

Tenho um formulário em HTML, e estou usando um código PHP para realizar o envio dos  dados via e-mail.
Porém, gostaria de enviar por e-mail, apenas os dados dos campos preenchidos, e seus respectivos nomes.

Exemplo:

[ ] Nuggets
[3] Hot Dog
[1] Cheese Burguer
[ ] Pizza
[ ] Salada

O e-mail vira com todos os text field, inclusive os itens que possuem nenhuma unidade marcada, e gostaria que viesse da seguinte maneira:

[3] Hot Dog
[1] Cheese Burguer

Estou utilizando o código abaixo pare fazer o envio do email com os campos(que no caso os campos não condizem com os de cima, foi apenas um exemplo):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "seuemail@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

Está tudo funcionando, customizei o código acima para colocar os campos que realmente preciso no formulário.
Acredito que seja necessário utilizar IF, neste arquivo em PHP, porém nao tenho certeza e nem ideia de como faze-lo.

Peço desculpas se o código do post foi colocado da maneira errada, mas é minha primeira vez no forum.(sim eu li as instruções)

Desde já, agradeço.

PS: Código HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="mail_haddor.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" size="40"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Como comentei inicialmente, o exemplo citado não condiz com o código de base que utilizei.
Neste caso, seria como, enviar e aparecer no corpo do e-mail, apenas os campos preenchidos como primeiro nome, segundo nome, e-mail.
Se preencher só o primeiro nome, não quero que venha por exemplo:

Nome: Mário
Segundo Nome:
E-mail:

Quero que apareça:

Nome: Mário

O exemplo foi com comida, pois será utilizado com alimentos.

Comment: Se possível clique em **[edit]** e poste seu código HTML.

Comment: O post já foi editado e acrescentei o código HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido.
Segue abaixo o código PHP que realiza a função descrita na dúvida do post:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "seuemail@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $val_fn = $first_name != '' ? 'Nome: '.$first_name.' '."\n\n" : '';
    $val_ln = $last_name != '' ? 'Sobrenome: '.$last_name.' ' : '';
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $val_fn . $val_ln . "escreveu a seguinte mensagem" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

Segui o exemplo de if(condição) ternário que o @Gilmar Alonso sugeriu, e modifiquei, pois não estava retornando da maneira desejada.

Utilizei as variáveis $val_fn e $val_ln para fazer a validação utilizando ternário nas variáveis que recebem o valor dos campos de nome e sobrenome, no caso $first_name e $last_name.

E depois, simplesmente coloco as variáveis de validação dentro da variável $message e construo minha mensagem de e-mail.

Agora, a partir disso, posso construir meu formulário com alimentos, como havia comentado na descrição do post. E receber o e-mail da maneira adequada, como gostaria de receber.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um IF ternário. receba os posts normalmentes, que virão vazios, e monta a mensagem com a seguinte estrutura!

```
$message = $first_name != '' ? 'Nome: '.$first_name : '' . " " . $last_name != '' ? 'Sobrenome: '.$last_name. " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" .
```

Comment: Obrigado @Gilmar Alonso.
Consegui entender o código que você sugeriu.
Porém ele não está retornando da maneira correta.

Se escrevo o nome, ele não aparece no e-mail nem mesmo o o texto "Nome:" antes, e a mensagem não aparece.

Se escrevo o sobrenome, ele aparece, se não escrevo, aparece só o texto "Sobrenome:". E em nenhuma das opções do sobrenome aparece a mensagem.

A mensagem só aparece, quando não digito nem nome e sobrenome.

Comment: `$message = $first_name != '' ? 'Nome: '.$first_name : '' . $last_name != '' ? 'Sobrenome: '.$last_name : '' . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];`

Veja como está o código

Comment: Gostaria de agradecer a ajuda, com o exemplo.
Não possuo conhecimento em PHP, mas já utilizei outras linguagens, e tenho uma base de lógica de programação, o que me permitiu entender o código, raciocinar e desenvolver da maneira correta que pudesse me atender.

Comment: Alguém, infelizmente, e acredito que não tenha sido você @Gilmar Alonso, não teve paciência, negativou meu post como "a pergunta não é clara ou não é útil".
É complicado entrar em um site de linguagens de programação, onde as pessoas tem um vasto conhecimento, e não serem capazes de entender uma simples questão, enquanto são capazes de realizar códigos complexos.
Recebi o mesmo tipo de reação do forum, em inglês.
E essa é uma dúvida que vi algumas pessoas terem também, durante minha pesquisa, so que as mesmas não obtiveram sucesso.

Comment: Mais uma vez agradeço a ajuda e continue tendo paciência de ajudar e entender a duvida dos outros, uma vez que possui conhecimento para isso.

Espero que o post possa ajudar outras pessoas também.

Obrigado.

Comment: Esse povo é complicado, acham que se não forem as dúvidas deles, ninguem tem o direito de perguntar!